# How to Backtest a Strategy in Python

Tags: python, stocks, trading

I need to be able to determine whether a particular "trade" (indicated by "signal") resulted in a profit or loss by indicating a win or loss for each.

I need Python to check the next location ( the **`signal`** or entry point or date + 1 ) in the High and Low lists  ( the lists: **`close`**, **`highs`**, and **`lows`** will have the same number of values ) for an increase in value equal to or greater than 2.5% at some point beyond the entry signal.

However, I also want Python to determine if the value drops 3% or more prior to appreciating 2.5% or more.

This must occur for each entry in `signal`.

In essence, I need a limit to sell at 102.5% and a stop at 97%.

Unfortunately, the code I developed so far doesn't seem to be working.

**What am I missing?**

```
signals = [1,5,7]
close   = [5,10,10,10.5,11,12,11.9,14,14,15,16]
highs   = [7,10.2,10.1,11,12,12.1,12.2,14.5,18,19,20]
lows    = [4,9.9,9.8,10,10,11.8,11.8,12,13.8,13.85,14]

for i in signals:
    entry = close[i]
    print i
    for high in highs[i+1:]:
        profit = ( ( high - entry ) / entry ) * 100
    for low in lows[i+1:]:
        loss   = ( ( low  - entry ) / entry ) * 100
    if abs( loss ) <  3:
        if profit  >= 2.5:
            print 'Win'
        else:
            print 'Loss'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `profit` is only calculated for `highs[-1]` while `loss` is only calculated for `lows[-1]`. Everything else is discarded, as you replace `profit` and `loss` in each loop.

You want to find the *set* of values where your condition is true. Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to put lows and highs together:

```
for i in signals:
    entry = float(close[i])
    for high, low in zip(high[i + 1:], low[i + 1:]):
        profit = ((high - entry) / entry) * 100
        loss = ((low - entry) / entry) * 100
        if loss > -3:
            if profit >= 2.5:
                print "Win"
            else:
                print "Loss"
```

Comment: I need it to look at each high and in the case that one is 2.5% higher than the entry point, while not having a low that is less than 3% below the entry point before the 2.5% increase, it will print "Win."

Comment: @user1526586: in pairs? So if high[3] is 2.5 higher, and low[3] is >  3% below? Your algorithm is not clear.

Comment: If the absolute value of the low > 3%, then it is no longer a win if it occurs before any high is 2.5% or higher.

Comment: @user1526586: that's not what I meant. Which low? Which high? You have lists of both, not one value of each.

Comment: Ok, on a given day, the stock has a high, a low, and a closing value. I'm assuming the purchase will occur at the closing value and each close, high, and low correspond to the other as far as date. Therefore, if a high on any day is 3% above the closing price on the day I purchased the stock, then I should be able to get my 2.5% profit. However, if at any point, their is a low that is below 3% loss between the day that the price increases to 2.5% or more,then the trade is a loss. I want to start at purchase date + 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user1526586: and what is date + 1? The value to the left or right in your lists when printed?

Comment: It should be the value to the right. Earlier dates on left and later dates on right.

Comment: @user1526586: you do realize you are asking people to write the code for you, instead of understand what you are doing wrong.. I'll update with more hints.

Answer (score 2):

Did you already check python-libraries for backtesting? In fact I use other libraries, but there are some very popular python-based solutions such as "pybacktest", "PyAlgoTrade", or "UltraFinance". Maybe integrating such a library could be advantageous for your use case...